# Allowing users to discard features added via PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I made a tool that adds some features into a layer which has to be in an edit session. If I want to stop the edit session without saving changes my new features already exist in the layer.

I used this kind of adding features:

```
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
if vlayer.isEditable():
    vlayer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature]) # QgsFeature() with geometry
```

Looks like QGIS thinks that I added them in a non-edit session. Any way to make it waiting for committing results?

Comment: You could use `vlayer.rollBack(True)` to remove any added features which have not been saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit vector layers in PyQGIS you **either use the layer (`QgsVectorLayer`) methods or the layer.dataProvider() (`QgsVectorDataProvider`) methods**. The former allows you to use handy edit commands like undo/redo and roll back, whereas the latter directly commits changes to the data source (and does it even faster than the former).

As seen in your code, you're using the latter, but your use case requires the former. That is, to be able to let the user choose whether or not to apply changes to your vector layer, **you need to use `QgsVectorLayer` methods** instead of `QgsVectorDataProvider` ones.

Namely, you need to do this:

```py
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
if vlayer.isEditable():
    vlayer.addFeatures([feature])  # No longer using dataProvider() here
```

After running the code snippet above, edits will be stored in an edit buffer, not in the layer itself. It is now up to the user whether to commit changes (and store them into the layer) or to discard them (known as roll back).

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers-with-an-editing-buffer) you need to call `commitChanges` or `rollBack` methods.

> For these methods to work, the layer must be in editing mode. To start the editing mode, use the startEditing() method. To stop editing, use the commitChanges() or rollBack() methods. The first one will commit all your changes to the data source, while the second one will discard them and will not modify the data source at all.

So I guess you need to call `rollback()` when you are done.

Comment: Turon, forgot to mention that my lines are within a PyQt tool in which user can perform changes in layer that should be only in edit session. After adding features by this tool I want user to decide save layer changes by closing edit session manually or discard them.